# How to draw half-transparent NSTableRowView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

I want to customize drawing of floating group row background and can't do it. Basically I want a partially transparent background (which always keeps the same look when scrolling or not), but something alters the appearance of my subclass of `NSTableRowView` when the table view is not scrolling (though when scrolling it looks as intended). 
Here's the code and the image explaining the issue.

```
- (void)drawBackgroundInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor colorWithCalibratedWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5] set];
    [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:dirtyRect] fill];
}
```

For table cell view I tried to use NSTableCellView, NSView and simple NSTextField (this is the one you see on the image), but the result is always the same.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix it by turning on Core Animation layer on the header cell view and its table view.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not doing anything other than filling the background of the row with a color, you should be setting the `backgroundColor` property of `NSTableRowView` instead of overriding `-drawBackgroundInRect:`.

If you do need this override for further customization, I noticed that you're forgetting to call `[super drawBackgroundInRect:dirtyRect]` in your implementation, which is likely responsible for the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Do you mean .backgroundColor? If so, then I tried to set it but it's always reset by table view. If I call super in drawBackgroundInRect: then it draws default gray background first and then my half transparent overlay over that gray background.

Comment: Yep, sorry that's what I meant.